# press button to open web page from app

Tags: iphone, xcode, html

I have an app that I want to interact with a web page.  Basically I want to press a button and the web page will open in a new view...

Sorry I wasn't clear, I am developing on a Mac for an iPhone.  Currently I have a "locate me" app that displays your Latitude and Longitude. I want to use those variables to populate 2 of the blanks on a PHP web page/form I have developed.

I have added a label and button to my current app, when the button is pressed the URL with the Lat and Long (as passed vars) are displayed in the label. I want those vars to appear on my web page.  Hope this is clearer...

---

***Solved:***  I just added these lines of code I found [here](http://snipplr.com/view/8475/open-url-in-safari/):

```
NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://www.cnn.com" ];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged it as xcode, I assume you are using a Mac? Or is this an iPhone question? Either way, I'd suggest looking in the /Developer/Examples/WebKit folder on your development box. It contains a number of samples for displaying web pages. You'd then link the button to opening the web page by creating a new web document.