# How to open a webpage using a button in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to open a webpage from a DashboardViewController by linking the URL to a button. I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)facebook:(id)sender {
    [[DashboardViewController sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]];
}
```

However this throws the error:

```
[DashboardViewController sharedApplication]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xaba8
2013-04-22 23:23:35.264 LoginScreen[37692:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[DashboardViewController sharedApplication]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xaba8'
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode. Also, there are dozens of duplicates of this question. You need to learn the basics of Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this question multiple times but none addressed this specific error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solved answer to your question -

1. [press button to open web page from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240372/press-button-to-open-web-page-from-app)
2. [Open web page inside iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120417/open-web-page-inside-ios-application)

Use a UIWebView which you can add as a subview to any other view, after which call loadRequest on with your URL.